# what is the derivative of $3\cos(\cos x)\;?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

what is the derivative of $3\cos(\cos x)\;?$

I think I need to use the chain rule and i believed it to be $3-\sin(\cos x)(-\sin x)$ but this is not the case.

Comment: @James that is incorrect as written.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: Surely a typo, but nothing he can do about it now except delete the comment and rewrite it. That's one thing I hate about the small window for editing comments here.

Comment: GAH! stupid typos.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}(3\cos(\cos (x)))'&=3(\cos(\cos (x)))'\\&=3(-\sin(\cos (x)))(\cos (x))'\\&=3(-\sin(\cos (x)))(-\sin (x))\\&=3\sin (x)\sin(\cos (x)).\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

You applied the chain rule correctly if you meant to write the derivative as a *product* of three factors, i.e. $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 3(-\sin(\cos x))\cdot(-\sin x).$$ You just need to simplify to get $$--3\sin(\cos x)\cdot \sin x = 3\sin(\cos x)\cdot \sin x$$ which can also be written $$3(\sin x)\sin(\cos x)$$

Writing it as you did, *without parentheses*, makes it look like $3-\sin(\cos x)( - \sin x)$, which looks like you are subtracting the two trigonometric factors from $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a deep breath and start with the derivative of the inner part:
$$
\cos'(x) = -\sin x
$$
then you use $$
(3\cos)' u = -3u'\sin u
$$with $u=\cos x$:

$$
\frac d{dx} 3\cos(\cos x) = -3(-\sin x) \sin(\cos x)
= 3\sin x \sin(\cos x)
$$